# Show $f(x)=x-x^2/2$ is not a contracting map on $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We define a contracting map as a function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \alpha|x-y|$ for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Consider $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ given by $f(x)=x-x^2/2$. I wish to show that this map is not contracting on $[0,1]$.

Suppose that such a constant $\alpha$ exists. By the mean value theorem, 
$$f'(c)=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq \alpha$$
for some constant $c\in (0,1)$, and thus $f'(c)=1-c\leq \alpha$. I don't see how this helps, since it implies that $1\leq c+\alpha$, which is not yet a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Option:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=$

$|x-y+(1/2)(x^2-y^2)|=$

$|(x-y)+(1/2)(x-y)(x+y)|=|(x-y)||1+(1/2)(x+y)|$.

$x,y \in [0,1] $: $1\le 1+(1/2)(x+y)\le 2$;

Hence?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Choose $x=0$. Then for any $y\in(0,1]$ there exists a $c\in (0,y)$ such that $\alpha\geq f'(c)=1-c$. Choose $y=1-\alpha$, which we can do because by assumption $\alpha\in (0,1)$, so $1-\alpha\in (0,1)$. Furthermore we must have $c<y$. Thus by what you have already discovered $\alpha\geq f'(c)=1-c> 1-(1-\alpha)=\alpha$, which is your desired contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier just to use the definition of derivative: $f'(0)=1$ so for any $\alpha<1$ there is an $0<x\le 1$ such that $\frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{|x-0|} >\alpha\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)|>\alpha|x-0|$ so $f$ is not a contraction.